# How to configure emacs to show documentation alongside completions while using gocode?

Tags: auto-complete-mode, documentation, golang

I have been using gocode with emacs and it gives completions of functions. Is there any way to get emacs to show the documentation of those functions in a pop up too. I am using auto-complete with go-mode.

Comment: `go-mode` has `godoc-at-point`, but I'm not sure you can integrate it into auto-complete mode (I'm not doubtful, I simply don't know).

Answer (score 2):

If you use [Icicles](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles) then you can use `C-M-RET` (or `C-M-mouse-2`) to see the full doc string (in `*Help*`) of any completion candidates. You can use the arrow keys `C-M-down` and `C-M-up` to cycle among candidates, showing their doc the same way.

Also, the first line of the doc string is shown in the mode-line, so just cycling among candidates using `down` etc. shows you that much, at least. (Dunno whether using `auto-complete-mode` at the same time as Icicles is a problem or is useful.)

See [Icicles - Get Help on Completion Candidates](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_A_Propos_d'Apropos#GetHelpOnCandidates).

Answer (score 1):

If you use `company-mode` (which is preferred by most over `autocomplete` these days), try [`company-quickhelp`](https://github.com/expez/company-quickhelp).